# Enroll MacOS 10.13 in FreeIPA domain?

Tags: macos, ldap, kerberos, freeipa

I tried following [this guide](https://www.freeipa.org/page/HowTo/Setup_FreeIPA_Services_for_Mac_OS_X_10.12) to enroll a mac on OS X 10.13.6 in my FreeIPA domain that all the linux machines on my home network are.

All the steps worked, but I can't log in with any freeipa users (not even through ssh).

And for some reason, when I set the LDAPv3 to use SSL, the ipa server shows as offline in System Preferences, but when I turn off SSL, it can connect just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Check SASL for LDAP

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string DIGEST-MD5" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/freeipa.genomics.local.plist 
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string CRAM-MD5" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/freeipa.genomics.local.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string NTLM" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/freeipa.genomics.local.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string GSSAPI" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/freeipa.genomics.local.plist 

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string DIGEST-MD5" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/freeipa.genomics.local.plist 
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string CRAM-MD5" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/freeipa.genomics.local.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string NTLM" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/freeipa.genomics.local.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add ':module options:ldap:Denied SASL Methods:' string GSSAPI" /Library/Preferences/OpenDirectory/Configurations/LDAPv3/freeipa.genomics.local.plist
```